# how to exit from exec 3>/dev/tcp/${ip} if remote machine takes time to respond

Tags: bash, shell

I am working on a script to get the application status if the application is reachable on particular port or not.
Below code is working fine if the remote port is active and stucked if the remote port is not active and takes time to respond.

## Code

```
  #!/usr/bin/bash
  TS="lava1/22"
  for ip in `echo ${TS}`
  do
    if(exec 3<>/dev/tcp/${ip}) 2> /dev/null;

    then
        echo -e "TS ${ip}  ..................................${GREEN[OK]${NORMAL}"
    else
         echo -e "TS${ip}  .................................. ${RED[FAIL]${NORMAL}"
    fi
done
```

## Below are results

```
jesadmin@lava$ ./a.sh
TS lava1/22  .................................. [OK]
```

## Below is with non-active port

```
jesadmin@lava$ ./a.sh

TS10.203.22.16/7122  .................................. [FAIL]
```

I am looking the immediate exit from exec if the remote is taking time to respond.

Can anyone guide me how to achieve this or any alternatives of this

Thanks

Comment: There's no tunable for this in bash - it's a very simple API. You're better off using a combination of traceroute & ping to check if the host is on (although ping might not respond), then `nc` for the actual connection, which has a timeout option.

Comment: nc is not installed on system.

Comment: A small bit of perl/python could accomplish something similar if you can't install `nc`; but the advice still stands of trying traceroute and ping first.

Comment: Ping is not recommended and most of the commands are not available such as traceroute on system.

Comment: Ping checks if a host is responding to ICMP echos. It doesn't check if an arbitrary port is open.

Answer (score 1):

As you're already using a subshell, the simplest is to explicitly run that subshell using `timeout` (from GNU coreutils):

```
timeout 7.5s bash -c "true <>/dev/tcp/$host/$port"
```

The exit status will be 0 for success, 1 for connection refused or other error within the time limit, and 124 if the command timed out.

In your code, that would look something like

```
#!/bin/bash
TS=(lava1/22 lava2/22)
max_time=15s
for ip in "${TS[@]}"
do
    if timeout $max_time bash -c "true <>/dev/tcp/$ip" 2>/dev/null
    then
        echo -e "TS ${ip}  .................................. ${GREEN}[OK]${NORMAL}"
    else
        echo -e "TS ${ip}  .................................. ${RED}[FAIL]${NORMAL}"
    fi
done
```

(I also fixed a couple of typos, and used a Bash array variable for `TS`; hope that helps!)

Answer (score -1):

you can include a timeout for your command itself. try using spawn command with a timeout
or sleep $yourMinutes & kill $PID

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  And you probably ought to state what package needs to be installed to provide the `spawn` command - I couldn't find it in the standard repositories.  Perhaps you meant `timeout` (in `coreutils`) or `timelimit`?  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.